# Sum of the series $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3\cdot 5}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7}+\ldots$

Tags: number-theory

Let $p_1=2,p_2=3,p_3=5,p_4=7,\ldots$ the sequence of primes. Since
$\lim_{k\to\infty }p_k=\infty$, it follows that the series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p_1p_2p_3\cdots p_k}=
\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3\cdot 5}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7}+\ldots
$$
converges. Can anyone know a good estimate of the sum? is it a known sum? Thanks.

Comment: You only need all $p_k\geq 2$ to get it to converge.

Comment: Numerical value is $$0.7052301717918009651474316828882485\cdots$$ It is the sum of the reciprocals of the primorials. No idea whether this constant has a name or has been further studied.

Comment: Interesting would be whether this number is irrational or even transcendental.

Comment: No extra information on [OEIS:A064648](https://oeis.org/A064648).

Comment: The only good way I can think of is $p_n\asymp n\log(n)$ but even then you end up with a product of logarithms which isn't much help. Better approximations of $p_n$ only yield knottier expressions.

Comment: @K.defaoite The question is not about a good approximation for $p$# , but for the sum which converges very quickly.

Comment: I think this number is irrational. http://www.tricki.org/article/To_prove_that_a_number_is_irrational_show_that_it_is_almost_rational applied to the partial sums.